# Plone store form inputs in a lightweight way

Tags: python, forms, plone

I need to store anonymous form data (string, checkbox, FileUpload,...) for a Conference registration site, but ATContentTypes seems to me a little bit oversized.

Is there a lightweight alternative to save the inputs - 
SQL and PloneFormGen are not an option

I need to list, view and edit the data inputs in the backend...

Plone 3.3.6
python 2.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uwosh.pfg.d2c (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uwosh.pfg.d2c/)

It's an adapter for PloneFormGen (I know you said you don't want to use it, but keep reading). It transform your data in real Archetype content and you can enable an optiona that make it works with anonymous users.

And it will work on Plone 3.3. also.

Another approach is our unreleased collective.signupsheet (https://github.com/RedTurtle/collective.signupsheet) that is based on uwosh.pfg.d2c, but it's focused on event subscription. However we never released it (use at your own risk).

Comment: Thank you, but I have partially complex forms, that cannot be designed/build with PFG (out of the box)....

Comment: So I don't understand what you want to do. You said that ATContentTypes is oversized to be used for your need but you have a very complex form... mmmhhh!
How can you implements the form? Raw HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [souper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/souper/1.0.1)

The description of the packages matches exact your requirement:
`ZODB Storage for lots of (light weight) data.`

There's a plone integration package [plone.souper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/souper.plone/1.1)

There's an also an implementation example, see [collective.pfg.soup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.pfg.soup/1.5.1)
**I guess this could fit your requirement.**

I remember a talk at the ploneconf 2013, as example for the performance of `souper`, someone imported wikipedia articles: [some slides](http://www.slideshare.net/Makina_Corpus/importing-wikipedia-in-plone)

btw: Well, I'm not sure about Plone 3.x / Python 2.4 support.

Comment: No, it won't run on Python 2.4 I fear

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a browser view that accepts and retrieves JSON data and then just do all of the form handling in custom HTML. The JSON could be stored in an annotation against the site root, or you could create a simple content type with a single field for holding the JSON and create one per record. You'll need to produce your own list and item view templates, which would be easier with the item-per-JSON-record approach, but that's not a large task.

If you don't want to store it in the ZODB, then pick whatever file store you want - like `shelf` - and dump it there instead.